# When reset is called asynchronously on react-hook-form's useFieldArray, reset doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form and react-navigation. In my use case, I'm using `useFieldArray` to control a growing array of inputs and I want to `reset` the form when the user press the `HeaderBackButton`. But when I pass `reset` to the `onPress` prop of `HeaderBackButton` and press the button, react-hook-form errors with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` whenever there is any change to the field array.
In the codebox below, you can append an item, and click `Reset` and reset the form. But clicking `Back` after appending an item would produce the error. This problem only appears in react-hook-form < 7.22.0

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hook-form-reset-usefieldarray-forked-yk7g4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import "./styles.css";

let renderCount = 0;

function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      loadState: "unloaded",
      names: []
    }
  });
  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "names"
  });

  renderCount++;

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Field Array </h1>
      <p>1. Append using the append button. </p>
      <p>2a. reset button works as expected</p>
      <p>2b. Back button, which is a HeaderBackButton errors out when there is any change to the field array</p>
      <span className="counter">Render Count: {renderCount}</span>
      <HeaderBackButton tintColor={'#FFFFFF'} 
        labelVisible={true}
        onPress={()=>{reset()}}
      />
      <button type='button' onClick={()=>reset()}>reset</button>
      <button type='button' onClick={()=>append('')}>append</button>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => (
            <Controller
              key={item.id}
              render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />}
              name={`names[${index}]`}
              control={control}
              defaultValue={item.lastName}
            />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: It seems the author has committed a bug fix for this. I'll update this thread once it is released and I've tried the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified that react-hook-form [7.22.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form/v/7.22.0) fixes this issue.

But the fix in 7.22.0 only makes all elements in the field array `undefined`. It does not clear out the field array, which is still causing problems for my specific case.

Author has identified crux of the problem is calling `reset` asynchronously. An updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-reset-usefieldarray-forked-yk7g4?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js) demonstrates that [7.22.2](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.22.2) of the library fixes the problem entirely.

This code works as expected with react-hook-form 7.22.2

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { HeaderBackButton } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import "./styles.css";

let renderCount = 0;

function App() {
  const { getValues, control, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      loadState: "unloaded",
      names: []
    }
  });
  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "names"
  });

  renderCount++;

  console.log(getValues());
  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Field Array </h1>
      <p>1. Append using the append button. </p>
      <p>2a. reset button works as expected</p>
      <p>
        2b. Back button, which is a HeaderBackButton does clear out the
        field array now
      </p>
      <span className="counter">Render Count: {renderCount}</span>
      <HeaderBackButton
        tintColor={"#FFFFFF"}
        labelVisible={true}
        onPress={() => reset({ names: [] })}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => reset({ names: [] })}>
        reset
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => append({ name: "abc" })}>
        append
      </button>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => (
          <Controller
            key={item.id}
            render={({ field }) => <input value={field.value} />}
            name={`names.${index}.name`}
            control={control}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```